# Getting space underneath table

Tags: css, html-table

I want a little bit of space underneath my table.

```
<table border="0" class="medtable">
    <tr> 
        <th>User</th>
        <th>From</th>
        <th>To</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        ...
    </tr>
</table>
```

This CSS

```
table
{
border:1px solid black;padding-bottom:15px
}
```

But space between the border at the bottom and the last bit of text in the table. So it is not what I want. Any tips?

Comment: Would be easier to look at if you could give us the HTML for your table as well :)

Comment: You want `margin-bottom` instead of `padding-bottom`, but depending on your other elements, the margin might collapse.

Comment: you are missing a semicolon after the 15px
hmm.. but imo this should work...

Comment: @cimmanon That works, I will accept as answer.

Answer (score 9):

You want `margin-bottom` instead of `padding-bottom`.  From outside to inside:  margin, border, padding, content.